# symfony 1.4 get forwarded action name

Tags: symfony-1.4

I need the name of current action, where I have been forwarded from a parent action class. When I try getting action name using context object, it gives me the name of my parent action.

```
$this->getContext()->getRequest()->getParameter('action')
```

Is there any way I get the name of forwarded action?

Answer (score 0):

The action in the request stays the same when you use `forward` (you forward the code execution to another action than the one originally called). If you used `redirect` then a http redirection would be performed and your way of reading the action would work.

You can always get the current action name in the controller with this simple call:

```
$this->getActionName();
```